# Can I run svn update and print each output on C# Windows Forms without delay?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, tortoisesvn

I'm checking if its possible to make C# run subversion commands and print each output in a listbox. On a button click I have:

```
    ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/k svn update D:\MyProject");
    cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.RedirectStandardError = true;
    cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    cmd.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process reg = Process.Start(cmd);
    using (System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = reg.StandardOutput)
    {
        output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
    using (System.IO.StreamReader myError = reg.StandardError)
    {
        error = myError.ReadToEnd();
    }
    lsbOutput.Items.Add(output + Environment.NewLine + error);

}
```

The issue is that the process is Synchronous, because when `StreamReader` is reading output, it could take a long time. Listbox is taking the output only when `svn update` is finished.

I would like to know if there is a way to update on-the-fly getting and printing each output response right away, instead of waiting the whole process to be completed.

Maybe I should use something like http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read output and error streams line by line in a different thread:

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    worker.ReportProgress(0, line);
}
```

using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx